# Ajax POST int to MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to POST an INT with Ajax to my MVC controller.

The script debugging confirms that my variable is an INT with a value (for example 8 and not a string "8"). All lines of code are executed and 
I recive my Alert error message.

I've got a breakpoint inside of my Action in the controller but I never get that far. I get a notice in my Action that a request failed, but it only say
"POST Order/Delete".  My Controller name is OrderController and Action name is Delete.

My JavaScript:

```
//Delete order
$(".deleteOrder").on("click", function () {

    var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));

    if (id !== null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Order/Delete",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/JSON;odata=verbose",
            data: id ,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Ok")
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
    }

});
```

My MVC Action

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        List<OrderRow> lstOrderRow = new List<OrderRow>();

        lstOrderRow = db.OrderRows.Where(x => x.OrderId == id).ToList();

        foreach(var row in lstOrderRow)
        {
            db.OrderRows.Remove(row);

        }

        Order order = new Order();

        order = db.Orders.Find(id);

        db.Orders.Remove(order);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

Comment: well shouldn't you pass up what it is? `data: "id=" + id`

Comment: I was going to suggest `data: { id: id }` - not sure now which is the correct way

Comment: Either way *should* work.  The overall point being that it needs to be a key/value pair, not just a value.

Comment: Tried both but it doesn't work. Browser debugger says HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:53445/Order/Delete

Comment: Does it matter that I'm calling the action Order/Delete from another View (Order/Detail)?

Comment: Use a Razor URL.Action helper to set the correct URL for the action method based on your routing rules and the deployed location of the app. Better than hard-coding it and then not realising when things change.

Comment: And putting RedirectToAction at the end of the method makes no sense, the whole point of ajax calls is to avoid postbacks, refreshes, redirects etc. The ajax code will not follow the Location header which the server sends as a result of this command. Surely you should be returning a JsonResult instead, or at least a string response of some kind. Also take out the contentType option from your ajax request, it's not necessary and it doesn't look valid

Comment: Also your action method has `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` but you do not send any such token in your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use the url like this by removing data field

```
url: "/Order/Delete/" + id,
```

or send the id in data as below

```
data: {id: id},
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: id}) 
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```